# OWIN e Katana - Como realmente funciona e como usar?

Tags: asp.net, owin

Nos últimos tempos tenho tentado entender melhor sobre o OWIN nos aspectos de por que usar ele, como ele funciona e como usar. Sobre o porquê de usar já perguntei aqui e já me convenci de que a maior motivação é conseguir deixar os componentes do ASP.NET (MVC, WebAPI, etc) mais modulares e independentes do assembly System.Web.dll pra aumentar a performance.

O que ainda não entendi é como ele funciona e como usar ele. Pelo que entendi ele basicamente conta com um `IDictionary<string, object>` chamado de Environment Dictionary e um delegate `Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task>` que basicamente aponta pra uma função que recebe o Environment Dictionary e retorna uma `Task`.

Daí eu ouvi dizer que isso desacopla a aplicação do servidor e permite a construção de pipelines de execução complexas. Eu realmente não entendi como isso funciona.

Além disso, pra realmente usar o OWIN, eu sei que se utiliza uma classe `Startup` com uma função de configuração que recebe um objeto que implementa `IAppBuilder`. Qual seria o papel dessa interface nisso tudo? Além disso, parece que tudo está conectado com o uso da função `Use` dessa interface. Novamente, o que realmente essa função faz e como realmente usamos ela?

Eu sei que ela que permite integrarmos o WebAPI, o Identity, etc. Mas não consigo entender ainda como isso tudo funciona e como usar.

Comment: É porque ainda é uma abordagem nova, que pouca gente domina. Por isso há pouco material preciso sobre o assunto.

Comment: É @Crood, eu achei poucas coisas sobre o OWIN por ai. Basicamente eu meio que me "acostumei" com ele por enquanto, mas queria entender mesmo o negócio. Ainda mais agora que vai ter o vNext ta mais importante entender isso.

Comment: vNext é o ".net sem compilar". Cara, até onde entendi, OWIN e outros projetos devem ser migrados para outras estruturas, então não se atenha muito ao que temos por enquanto. Não tem versão RTM ainda

Comment: Aqui tem um post sobre essas mudanças: http://eduardopires.net.br/2014/05/o-futuro-do-asp-net-vnext-mvc-6/.

Comment: Favoritada. Vou tentar responder logo.

Answer (score 10):

O principal objetivo do OWIN é poder desenvolver aplicativos e componentes que sejam mais fáceis de escrever e de consumir que da maneira do ASP.NET tradicional, além de eliminar a dependência do uso do IIS, possibilitando ao desenvolvedor o uso de um hospedeiro alternativo desenvolvido livremente pela comunidade.

Pra isso, o OWIN faz largo uso de estruturas dinâmicas, mais presentes em linguagens e Frameworks modernos, como o Ruby on Rails juntamente com o Rack, e máxima simplificação do ambiente e execução de tarefas.

Este `Environment Dictionary` é o dicionário que configura o ambiente. Apesar do ASP.NET MVC5 ser um Framework de desenvolvimento bastante intuitivo e fácil de desenvolver, sua configuração fica tremendamente burocrática quando ele precisa admitir uma nova topologia de requisições, como por exemplo a Web API 2 (versão da Microsoft para o padrão REST API). Ou seja, a aplicação pode ter vários dicionários de ambiente, sendo cada um para uma necessidade (um para configurar retorno em Razor, outro para JSON, e assim por diante).

Já o `Application Delegate` na verdade é uma assinatura de função, usada como interface entre os componentes de uma aplicação OWIN. Como toda a aplicação utiliza uma mesma interface, tanto faz se a aplicação vai devolver no fim da requisição uma página HTML, um JSON ou um XML (ou um outro formato que possa surgir no futuro): a interface para o processamento e retorno da requisição é a mesma.

O [Katana](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/) é uma das propostas de implementação do modelo OWIN, e possivelmente a mais pobre de exemplos (a maioria deles devolve apenas `text/plain`, mas [há algumas tentativas de integrar o Katana com o Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2013/02/06/owin-and-razor.aspx)).

Repare que, até a publicação desta resposta, o `handler` de Razor não foi exatamente implementado pela equipe oficial. Isto responde à parte da sua pergunta sobre a classe `Startup`: ela inicializa `handlers` somente, e são os `handlers` que possibilitam o uso de mecanismos que conhecemos, como o Razor. Seria uma espécie de "organizador de interfaces": ali se faz o registro de quais tecnologias serão usadas para processar as requisições.

Há outros projetos mais maduros que o Katana. São eles:

- [SignalR](http://signalr.net)
- [FubuMVC](http://mvc.fubu-project.org)
- [NancyFX](http://nancyfx.org)

No decorrer dos dias vou melhorar esta resposta com exemplos e devo colocar um projetinho no GitHub com uma implementação funcional do que seria uma aplicação MVC com Razor em cima de OWIN, usando o Katana.

Answer (score 8):

Nesse post do Eduardo Pires em [O Futuro do ASP.NET vNext – MVC 6](http://eduardopires.net.br/2014/05/o-futuro-do-asp-net-vnext-mvc-6/) ele explica de maneira bem simples. Em resumo nas palavras dele você pode entender da seguinte maneira:

O OWIN define uma interface padrão entre servidores Web e aplicações .NET.
O objetivo da interface OWIN é desacoplar o servidor e a aplicação, incentivar a criação de módulos simples para o desenvolvimento em ASP.NET, e, por ser um padrão aberto, estimular o ecossistema open source de ferramentas .NET de desenvolvimento Web.

Resumidamente o OWIN é uma camada de abstração entre o server e a aplicação.

> **OWIN**
>
> O objetivo do OWIN é que novos componentes possam ser facilmente desenvolvidos e > consumidos, porém de forma agnostica, ou seja, que possam rodar em outras plataformas como Unix (Mac/Linux) e que possam ser portados de uma plataforma para outra sem necessidade de  recompilação.
>
> - É um “standart” uma especificação.
> - Não existe exatamente como código ou componente.
> - É a descrição de como idealmente o comportamento de sua implementação
>     deve funcionar.

E o katana:

> **Katana**
>
> É uma implementação Microsoft da especificação OWIN no ASP.NET.
>   A Microsoft apostou na proposta do OWIN e o implementou nos projetos ASP.NET SignalR e ASP.NET WebAPI, essa implementação recebe o nome de Katana Project. Mais tarde o ASP.NET Identity surgiu implementando bibliotecas do Katana Project também.
>   Além da Microsoft, outros projetos implementam OWIN como NancyFx, FubuMVC, NOWIN etc.

E como complemento ainda terá o **Helios**

> **Helios**
>
> A implementação do OWIN atrávés do Katana Project proporcionou a criação de componentes ASP.NET muito mais leves, performáticos, independentes de plataforma e SelfHost, porém caso seja necessário contar com alguns recursos que o Host ASP.NET clássico (IIS) provê, tudo isso fica a cargo do desenvolvedor da aplicação.
>
> O IIS apesar de trabalhar apenas no pipeline do ASP.NET clássico (System.Web) possui uma série de benefícios que nem sempre podem ser deixadas de lado:
>
> IIS lida com gerenciamento da vida útil aplicação.
>   Ele pode suspender (em vez de encerrar) processos que estão ociosos para ajudar a equilibrar os recursos disponíveis do sistema.
>   IIS oferece um cache de modo de usuário embutido e pode comprimir automaticamente o conteúdo dos responses se for o caso.
>   IIS suporta filtragem de requests e transient worker process identities.
>   Mais de 10 anos de implementações e melhorias de segurança.
>   No cenário do Self Host você é responsável por muitas das responsabilidades que o IIS toma conta, além disso ele já existe para isso por que não utilizá-lo?
>   São esses os motivadores do Project Helios, porém devido à necessidade do IIS trabalhar no pipeline no System.Web muita performance seria perdida, por isso o Project Helios trabalha apenas com o “Core” do IIS o utilizando como uma espécie de API, o “Core” do IIS é extremamente rápido e poderoso, pois disponibiliza apenas as suas funcionalidades sem depender do pipeline do ASP.NET clássico (System.Web).
>
> O Project Helios oferece suporte aos projetos desenvolvidos em Katana (OWIN), porém não é dependente dele para ser utilizado, é possível desenvolver uma aplicação baseada apenas em Project Helios que rodará apenas no padrão IIS e não terá opções de SelfHost e multiplataforma, em uma arquitetura de aplicações para Windows pode ser muito vantajoso, pois é pelo menos 96% mais rápido que o ASP.NET clássico.

Dê uma olhadela no link, tenho certeza que gostará das novidades.