# Relação entre Middleware e Application Delegate

Tags: .net, asp.net, owin

Estou estudando o OWIN e sua implementação Katana pela Microsoft. Já perguntei sobre o assunto [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16139/owin-e-katana-como-realmente-funciona-e-como-usar) e as respostas já ajudam a ter uma boa visão geral do assunto. Indo mais a fundo encontrei essa dúvida. Na especificação são propostos dois objetos pro funcionamento de tudo: o environment dictionary e o application delegate.

Pelo que entendi a intuição por trás disso é a seguinte: o environment dictionary tem todos os dados da requisição HTTP e da resposta. O application delegate, por outro lado, é um ponteiro pra uma função que recebe o environment dictionary e retorna uma Task. Dessa forma, o application delegate, pelo que eu entendi recebe o environment dictionary com os dados da requisição, e é capaz de modificar a resposta de forma assíncrona.

Até aí tudo bem. Minha dúvida é o fato de existirem os middleware. Pelo que entendi os middleware são basicamente componentes que podemos plugar na pipeline e que são capazes de interferir na requisição modificando a resposta. Por exemplo o *Cookie Authentication Middleware* pode ser plugado na pipeline e manipula a resposta de forma a implementar autenticação por cookies. Da mesma forma, podemos plugar o WebAPI que é capaz de manipular a requisição e fornecer as funcionalidades de um serviço RESTful.

Basicamente, parece existir uma relação bem próxima entre os middleware e o application delegate. Minha dúvida, na verdade, é a seguinte: por aplicação construída em cima do OWIN existe apenas **um** application delegate ou vários que trabalham juntos? Nesse caso como o application delegate se relaciona com os middleware?

Imagino que seja da seguinte forma: existe um application delegate por aplicação e quando usamos o método de extensão `Use` pra adicionar um middleware basicamente o que acontece é que o `Invoke` do middleware é adicionado ao delegate. Dessa forma, o application delegate consegue executar todas as tarefas em sequência, uma de cada middleware, permitindo que cada middleware manipule a requisição um após o outro na sequência de registro. É assim mesmo que funciona?

Answer (score 1):

Os middlewares são funções que recebem o environment dictionary como parâmetro, e logo após chamam o próximo middleware, que também é uma função que recebe o environment dictionary. Assim se qualquer middleware não chamar o próximo middleware ele interrompe completamente o 'pipeline' e por exemplo, o request não chegará nem ao controle MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Seu estudo está correto.

quando você utiliza o seguinte trecho de código:

```
// vNext
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    // algum funcionalidade
}
```

Você está apenas adicionando a função a uma lista interna. Todos os items dessa lista serão chamados, dependendo do middleware a resposta pode ser gerada ou passada para o próximo middleware registrado (note que isso influencia em um controle maior de cada requisição, WebSockets por exemplo, onde a conexão e respostas tem um comportamento diferente e até mesmo a autenticação por Cookie que você mencionou).

é possível ver isso em detalhes aqui:

> http://whereslou.com/2014/05/28/asp-net-moving-parts-ibuilder/

e aqui:

> http://benjamincollins.com/the-katana-pipeline/

Especificação do Owin:
http://owin.org/

E aqui está o código por trás disso:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Owin/Builder/AppBuilder.cs